# How does IOS fulfill wifi captive portal auto-login?

Tags: ios, portal

It is a very useful function. I am curious about how engineers fulfill it.

There are different log-in pages from different wifi hotspots.I think HTTP POST with one username and one password can log in. But how to make it with compatibility?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Many captive portals use [WISPr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISPr).

How this works is that the HTML that comes back from the captive portal contains a piece of XML whose format is specified by the WISPr 'standard'.  In there there's a login URL, logout URL and other stuff.

The captive portal generates this HTML no matter which URL you're trying to load from your app.

By sending username and password to the supplied login URL result in internet access.

Comment: Thanks! meaning-matters. But this can only auto log-in WISPr AP. Seems IOS can recognize other type and auto log-in it.

Comment: Yes, there are other protocols, but these are working in similar ways. What is you question???

Comment: I want to find a method to save the username and passwd, and auto log-in for all types of wifi hotspot with captive portal. I noticed IOS accomplished all the work but I don't know how...Sorry my expression was not clear. ^ ^